# Create list from array values based on values in 2 different variables python

Tags: python

I have a problem I am not sure how to formulate this but I provided some explanation. I have generated a list of strings e.g `s = ["BB", "BB", "CD", "BA"]`.

Each member of s can generate any of `b = "B"` or `"C"` or `"D"` or `"A"` i.e just a single value as first variable and any combination of values of b or single value of `b` as variable `a`, e.g `a = ["B", "A", "D"]` or `a = ["B"]` or `a = ["B", "C"]` as a second value. i.e it can be any combination of value not more than 3 or a single value. `b = "B"` or `"C"` or `"D"`.

I have an array of class 'numpy.ndarray' of values. I wish to assign the values to a given variable e.g `myvar` and `myvar2`, depending on values in `a` and `b`. The array is the length of `s`. e.g `[[ 1, 1, 0, 1], [ 0, 1, 0, 2], [ 0, 0, 0, 3], [ 1, 1, 0, 1]]` and each column in the array represents `A, B, C, D` but not included in the array.

The steps:

```
for each member of s i.e length of s:
    if the member generates value of b as B and value of a as B, A, C:
        check 2nd column in matrix, pick the value and add it to my_variable
        check columns 2, 1 and 3 representing B,A,C and add the values to my_variable
        output result for each member of s because each member of s will generate a and b
```

what I have done so far:

```
s = ["BB", "BB", "CD", "BA"]
n = [[ 1, 1, 0, 1],[ 0, 1, 0, 2],[ 0, 0, 0, 3],[ 1, 1, 0, 1]]
a = ["B", "A", "D"]
b = "B"
myvar = []
myvar2 =[]
for x in s:
    for y in a:
        for i in n:
            if y == "A":
                myvar.append(i[0])
            elif y == "B":
                myvar.append(i[1])
            elif y == "C":
                myvar.append(i[2])
            elif y == "D":
                myvar.append(i[3])
print(myvar)
```

How do I select values for `b` and append to `myvar2` then merge `myvar` and `myvar2`separately for each item in `s`? The result I have so far is wrong because I get all values in `myvar` as one instead of for length `s`. My desired result after merging will be:

result = [value for b, values for a] for each member of s. e.g val for `a = [[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]` val for b = [1].

Final result = `[[1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1]]`. same length as `s`.

Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of what the output should be?  Your question is very confusing.

Comment: Should I add the example as comment or to my original post?

Comment: To the original post

Comment: @James. I already did that. I find myself using multiple if, else, elif statements and it seem not pythonic or maybe I am wrong but am not sure how to go around it.

Comment: I still have no idea what your question is asking.  You are iterating of `s`, but nothing happens with `x` in your code.  How are the values of `s` supposed to be used?

Comment: I was able to solve it after hours of working on it. I don't think I used an efficient method though because of many if and elif statements. Can I post my solution for input? If so, will it be a new post or as a response to my question. Someone can probably give me a more efficient way maybe.

Comment: Please post your code at the end of your question above. Maybe someone will look at improving it for you!